# Web page not displaying images on website. Google Chrome only

Tags: jquery, html, css, google-chrome

I have just launched my website. It all works fine apart from one page will not displaying any images at all. THIS IS ONLY A PROBLEM ON GOOGLE CHROME. Here is the link to my web page: http://michaelwillisdesign.co.uk/Advertising.html

Could someone have a snoop through and give me a reason why? I've been racking my brains and can't figure out why.

Thanks

Comment: What format and colour profile have you used when saving out your JPG files? I know some browsers have issues when a CMYK profile is used instead of RGB. If you used Photoshop, make sure you used the 'Save for Web...' option, not the normal 'Save...'

Comment: it works fine for me. looks good btw

Comment: I found a style rule in the image: `display:none !important;` Don't know why this doesn't affect other browsers (I'm using Opera) but it is something you should look into.

Comment: It's working fine for me. A little bit slow to load up, but can see all the images.

Comment: Pause adblock, see the pictures.

Comment: Pause adblock did work? Why isit doing this?

Comment: See my answer. I think it has to do with the name of the pictures ("images/advertising-second-image.jpg"). The internal logic must be blocking them because the name contains the word "advertising"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue is caused because you have an ad blocker plugin that is blocking the images. It happens to me too (I'm using AdBlock): the ad blocker considers that those pictures are publicity (they are actually pictures of banners and ads) and blocks them.

I don't know exactly how each ad blocker works, but you could try some of these general recommendations to avoid getting your pictures blocked when they are not really ads:

- Change the image names to something that doesn't include the word "ad" or "advertisement" or "advertising" or "publicity" (or any synonyms or words derived from them).
- Same as above but for class names and ids.
- Use image sizes that are not common in ads (e.g.: 728x90, 300x250, 300x600...)

And check these questions for reference (although I don't know if AdBlock is the one you are using):

- [How to stop adblock plus blocking images in HTML page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17255493/how-to-stop-adblock-plus-blocking-images-in-html-page)
- [How Adblock Plus works in Chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8715904/how-adblock-plus-works-in-chrome)
- [Getting "net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT" error on some AJAX calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23341765/getting-neterr-blocked-by-client-error-on-some-ajax-calls)

Comment: Fantastic answer, thanks for your help. It all works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

You have an error:

jquery.imageScroll.js on line 222

```
Uncaught Error: You need to provide either a data-img attr or an image option
```

This could be causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be working just fine for me in Chrome, Firefox and even IE.

Maybe try turning off any plugins/extensions in Chrome (adblock, etc), and see if they're interfering with the images being rendered.